# Navigate images in photoswipe manually on click of image(previous and next)

Tags: javascript, html, photoswipe

I am using photoswipe in my mobile application.

We are showing the images in a target `div`, we are not using the full screen view.

A requirement came in to not have the built in toolbar visible and have an arrow image on the left and right of the div to move to the previous and next images and also allow swiping. How do I call the JavaScript in `photoswipe.js` to do this manually on the click of an image.

Comment: I found the answer after some digging and after doing many complicated things.  The answer is quite simple.

Since I have an instance of the PhotoSwipe object(psInstance), you simply do:
   psInstance.next(); OR
   psInstance.previous();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some digging and after doing many complicated things.  The answer is quite simple.

Since I have an instance of the PhotoSwipe object(psInstance), you simply do:
   psInstance.next(); OR
   psInstance.prev();

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with the API. Try it with this approach to catch the click event:

```
/*slide to the next item on img click*/

lightBox.framework.bind(lightBox.scrollWrap, 'pswpTap', function(e) {
    pswp.next();
});
```

'pswp' => your PhotoSwipe object.